# O que é "extract" em PHP?

Tags: php

Estava a fazer analise de um Código **PHP**, e num **script** usou-se **extract**.

Procurei em algums documentos PHP e os exemplos são meio abstratos e infelizmente não percebi grande coisa.

Gostaria num caso geral saber o que faz o **extract** em PHP ? (Se possivel um exemplo concreto).

Comment: Um conselho: evite o `extract`. Não é legal fazer variáveis aparecerem magicamente num arquivo de código ou, pior, função. Deixa o código mais difícil de entender. Se for usar isso, no mínimo documente bem o que estiver sendo importado.

Comment: Foi por uma necessidade specifica... Contudo valeu pela dica, farei pesquisas acerca disso !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pega um array associativo e declara variáveis, tendo como nome as chaves, e o conteúdo da variável, o valor do array referente a chave.

Segue um exemplo:

```
$teste = ["variavel" => "valor da variável"];

extract($teste);

echo $variavel;   //vai imprimir "valor da variavel"
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php

Aqui tem outros exemplos bem intuitivos.